# RX Subject, group/correlate until a condition is met

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a stream of items, and I want to create a subscription that groups by a property until a condition is met.

For example, let's say I want to group `EventItem`s by Name, until a specific `Id` is observed. The point of this is to correlate events until we see a specific `Id` that signals that there will be no more events to correlate. Then I want to perform some action with each group of correlated events.

```
public class EventItem
{
  public int Id { get; set }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

// Using a Subject since it seems the simplest way
Subject<EventItem> eventStream;
...

// A seperate thread pushes EventItem objects into the Subject
eventStream.OnNext(eventItem);

// Struggling here...
IDisposable subscription = eventStream.????
```

I've tried several combinations with `GroupBy`, `GroupByUntil`, `TakeUntil`, `TakeWhile` etc, but I can't figure out how to do this (I'm rather inexperienced with Rx)

Comment: Can I ask if `IDisposable subscription = eventStream.TakeWhile(ei => ei.Id != 42).GroupBy(x => x.Name).Subscribe(y => { });` isn't what you're looking for?

Comment: @Enigmativity that does seem to work, but only once; that is, once I've seen a group, I don't see any more (has the subscription ended?)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data that demonstrates what you mean?

Comment: After the 1st time the code inside `.Subscribe(y => { ... })` runs, it never runs again - the subscription is only 'fired' (sorry, don't know the correct Rx lingo!) for the 1st matching group.

Comment: Please can you provide some sample data that demonstrates what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on @Shlomo's answer and the OP's comments about wanting it to not complete

```
var subscription = producer
        .TakeWhile(ei => ei.Id != 42)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
        .Select(o => o)
        .SelectMany(o => o.ToList()) //If you want y to be IList<EventItem>, use this line. If you prefer y to be IObservable<EventItem>, comment out.
        .Repeat()
        .Subscribe();
```

**Original Answer**

Does this work?

```
        Subject<Notification> producer = new Subject<Notification>();

        //This way there's only one producer feeding the group and the duration
        var connectedProducer =
            producer
                .Publish()
                .RefCount();

        connectedProducer
            .GroupByUntil(
                item => item.Name,
                item => connectedProducer.Where(x=> x.Id == 3))
            .SelectMany(result =>
            {
                return result.Aggregate<Notification, List<Notification>>(new List<Notification>(), (dict, item) =>
                {
                    dict.Add(item);
                    return dict;
                });
            })
            //not sure if you need this but just a way to filter out the signal
            .Where(item => item.First().Id != 3) 
            .Subscribe(results =>
            {
                //This will only run after a "3" is passed in and then you get a list of everything passed in with the names
                //not sure if you wanted intermediate results or for it all to just come through once the signal indicates processing
            });
```

I based this off of a previous answer of mine and just modified it slightly.
[Rx grouped throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694010/rx-grouped-throttling/42703750#42703750)

Answer (score 2):

I know there's an accepted answer already, but it seems over complicated. Working off @Enigmativity's comment:

```
var subscription = eventStream
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(o => o.TakeWhile(ei => ei.Id != 42))
    .SelectMany(o => o.ToList()) //If you want y to be IList<EventItem>, use this line. If you prefer y to be IObservable<EventItem>, comment out.
    .Subscribe(y => {});
```

Comment: I tried this one as written and I'm just getting an empty list on y. I moved the TakeWhile between the eventStream and GroupBy then it worked. Though it also completes but that can easily be taken care of with a Repeat if OP wants it to keep going.

Comment: This works, but the results are missing the last event (e.g. the one with `Id == 42`. I can combine yours and the accept answer tho, to get something simple that works (sorry for the formatting...): `this.subscription = this.eventStream.GroupByUntil(x => x.Name, x => this.eventStream.Where(y => y.Id == 42)).SelectMany(x => x.ToList()).Subscribe(x => { });`

Comment: That looks good too :-)  One thing that will help guide these questions is showing what you expect for the input and output. For example in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694010/rx-grouped-throttling/42703750#42703750 . As you can tell there were a few interpretations of your question.

Comment: @ShaneNeuville good advice for any future Rx questions I have, thanks :)