# Reactive Extensions: how to sample the latest value from IGroupedObservable

Tags: c#, .net, reactive-programming, system.reactive, rx.net

I have the following unit test where I am trying to group objects from a source observable by their identifier and sample them every 50 ticks. However, the code with the `GroupBy`, `SelectMany` -> `Sample` gives a different output than the expected output. It returns OnNext@280, OnNext@380 and OnCompleted@380.

When I run the test with only the `Sample` method the output meets the expectation as can be seen in the `AssertEqual` call.

What am I doing wrong here? I expect that both versions should produce the same output since the identifiers of all products are, in this case, the same.

Ps: I have already checked [this question about the same kind of operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823090/is-it-possible-to-sample-the-latest-item-in-a-hot-observable-grouped-by-key) and [this question on grouped throttling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694010/rx-grouped-throttling) + the reactive source unit tests.

```cs
public class ObservableTests : ReactiveTest
    {
        [Fact]
        public void sample_test()
        {
            // Arrange
            var productPrice = new ProductPrice("1", 10);
            var productPrice2 = new ProductPrice("1", 20);
            var productPrice3 = new ProductPrice("1", 30);
            var productPrice4 = new ProductPrice("1", 40);
            var productPrice5 = new ProductPrice("1", 50);
            var productPrice6 = new ProductPrice("1", 60);

            var testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
            var observable = testScheduler.CreateHotObservable(
                OnNext(230, productPrice),
                OnNext(260, productPrice2),
                OnNext(280, productPrice3),
                OnNext(340, productPrice4),
                OnNext(360, productPrice5),
                OnNext(380, productPrice6),
                OnCompleted<ProductPrice>(380));

            // Act

            // WORKS
            //var result = testScheduler.Start(
            //    () =>
            //        observable
            //            .Sample(TimeSpan.FromTicks(50), testScheduler));

            // DOESNT WORK
            var result = testScheduler.Start(
                () =>
                    observable
                        .GroupBy(value => value.Identifier)
                        .SelectMany(groupedObservable => groupedObservable.Sample(TimeSpan.FromTicks(50), testScheduler)));

            result.Messages.AssertEqual(
                OnNext(250, productPrice),
                OnNext(300, productPrice3),
                OnNext(350, productPrice4),
                OnNext(400, productPrice6),
                OnCompleted<ProductPrice>(400));
        }

        private class ProductPrice
        {
            public ProductPrice(string identifier, decimal price)
            {
                this.Identifier = identifier;
                this.Price = price;
            }

            public string Identifier { get; }

            public decimal Price { get; }
        }
```

Comment: What are the `OnNext` and `OnCompleted`? Are these custom methods?

Comment: These are methods you get by inheriting from `: ReactiveTest`, which is required to test reactive extensions code.

Comment: Vincent ahh, I didn't know it, thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I would like to comment that IMHO the Rx `Sample` operator has a weird behavior. I can't understand its sampling logic, and so I can't predict when it will emit the next element. If I needed a predictable/deterministic sampling behavior, I would consider making a custom `Sample` operator, probably composed by the `Interval`+`WithLatestFrom` operators.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but it works exactly as expected. The `groupedObservable` is created and subscribed to only after first element had been emitted - at 230 tick. So starting from that point in time the sampling will begin in that group, giving you results at  280, 330, 380 etc...

In your working example without grouping the observable is created at tick 100 and subscribed to at 200 (default settings for this overload of `TestScheduler.Start` method), so the first sampled element is emitted at 250.